# The meaning of equality in a complete orthogonal basis expansion of $L^2$ and point-wise equality.

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Given an element $u\in L^2(0,1)$ and a complete orthonormal basis $(e_n)_n$ we have the convergence of the 'Fourier-Bessel' series

$$
u_m= \sum^m_{n=0}\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n \to \sum^\infty_{n=0}\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n
$$

in $L^2(0,1)$. In particular we know that $||u-u_m|| \to 0$ as $m\to\infty$, and what's more is that since the basis $(e_n)_n$ is maximal we can actually prove that $||u-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n||=0$.

Therefore, I think that the equality $u=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n$ is equivalent to the following:

$$
u(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n(x) \quad \text{for almost all } x\in(0,1) \tag1
$$

which would make sense since $L^2(0,1)$ is actually the set of equivalence classes of square integrable functions which differ up to a set of measure zero.

Is this true?

If yes, does this mean that the RHS of (1) converges point-wise a.e. on $(0,1)$?

If yes, is it possible to replace $(e_n)_n$ with square integrable functions $(\phi_n)_n$ such that $[e_n]=[\phi_n]$ (i.e. so they are equal in $L^2(0,1)$) and we have the point-wise equality

$$
u(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\langle u,e_n\rangle \phi_n(x) \quad \text{for all } x\in(0,1)\tag2
$$
and if so is it possible to explicitly construct such a sequence $(\phi_n)_n$?

Help with answering any of the above would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write down an infinite series, you always implicitly assume in which sense the series converges. In the case of the series you wrote, it is implicitly assumed that the series converges in $L^2$, not a.e. And in general, $L^2$ convergence does not imply convergence a.e.

Now, this case (Fourier-Bessel series) is not the most general case of $L^2$ convergence, so one could in principle still hope to have convergence a.e. In fact, it may happen that for some complete basis one in fact has convergence a.e. A very famous example is that of Fourier series, see  [Carleson’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem) .

For more general orthonormal basis, I think convergence a.e. is not true in general (I guess… simply because Carleson’s theorem would be trivial at that point in the $L^2$ case). Maybe you could try to find a counterexample yourself.

To answer to the last question, keep in mind that a.e. convergence of a (countable) sequence of $L^2$ functions does not depend on the representatives you may choose in the equivalence classes (simply because a countable union of sets of measure zero still has measure zero). Therefore, even if you modify the basis with functions that agree a.e., you cannot obtain convergence a.e. with the new basis $(\phi_n)_n$ if you don’t have convergence a.e. with the original basis $(e_n)_n$ in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lorenzo! I am aware that convergence in $L^2$ in general does not imply convergence a.e., however I thought that since $||u-\lim u_m||=0$ and therefore $\int|u(x)-\lim u_m(x)|^2dx=0$, since $|u(x)-\lim u_m(x)|$ is positive we have it is equal to $0$ a.e. . However what you say about Carleson's theorem concerns me.

Comment: N.B. there is a nice convergence result on orthonormal series (ONS) in $L^2$, and when they converge a.e. known as the Rademacher-Menchov Theorem, however this concerns a.e. convergence and doesn't talk about a.e. equality of a ONS to the function it approximates in $L^2$.

Comment: What you just wrote is true, but it just means that two given functions are equal a.e. It just says nothing about the sequence of converging functions and how they converge (more precisely, the "lim" that you are writing is still an L^2 limit, not a pointwise limit; that's why it is important to keep in mind in which sense the things you write are converging).

Comment: Let me insist on the following: the fact that $u$ equals the limit of the $u_n$ a.e. is just another way of writing that $u$ is equal to the infinite series a.e. (WARNING: here I am assuming that the limit and the series are DEFINED to be limit/series converging in $L^2$, otherwise you simply cannot define them as you don't know if they are converging a.e.). There is no difference. Thus, the fact that $u$ equals the $L^2$ series a.e. is not something you need to prove. What you may want to prove is the a.e. convergence of the series, which you just know it converges in L2.

Comment: (sorry, I rewrote my comment)

Comment: I agree with your first point, $u_m$ are the partial sums, and yes lets assume everything does indeed converge in $L^2$.  I think I see what you mean, but first let me clarify, do think it's true that $u$ is equal to its ONS expansion point-wise a.e.? (this is what I thought I proved with my previous comment). If so, then what I think you're saying is,  that it is true that for a.e. $x\in(0,1)$, $u(x)=(\lim u_m)(x)$, where the limit is in $L^2$. But, what we do not have, is that $(u_m(x))_m$, which is the sequence of partial sums of the series evaluated at $x$, converges to $u(x)$ a.e.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135672/discussion-between-lorenzo-pompili-and-valcofadden).